# postgresql/postgis

Tags: sql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have a created a Point Geometry Column (coordenadas) in Postgres/Postgis using the following command line:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public', 'tb_amostra', 'coordenadas', 4326, 'POINT',2,false);
```

I have two columns, LONGITUGE and LATITUDE, in the tb_amostra table and I need to create points with 8 decimal digits for (lon, lat) into coordenadas column based on the values in LONGITUDE and LATITUDE columns.
 Any help on that please?
 Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tb_amostra SET coordenadas = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326);
```

Comment: @ lat long I got a long string (0101000020E6100000324ABF58F2EB36C06C46F28B25DF44C0) as an outcome after running the UPDATE command line you suggested me. It seems something went wrong. Any comment on that?

Comment: should not the update command create a value into the coordenadas column as this: POINT(lon,lat)?